# Авторизация в телеграмм боте на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, авторизация, auth

Всем привет! Пишу бота в телеграмме на python, столкнулся с проблемой: Возможно ли в боте реализовать авторизацию? т.е.: существует некая  БД, и чтоб пользователь мог получить некоторую информацию из неё он должен быть авторизирован по электронной почте и паролю, не понимаю как это возможно реализовать..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У каждого юзера в телеграме есть его `user_id`. Его ты получаешь через `message.user.id`.

Создаешь массив с ID юзеров, у которых есть доступ к боту, и в `message_handler` проверяшь, есть ли этот юзер в массиве.

```
@tb.message_handler(commands=['start', 'go'])
def start_handler(message):
    global ids # массив с айди пользователей, которые допущены
    if message.from_user.id not in ids:
        tb.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибся адресом, дружок')
    else:
        msg = tb.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, чем займёмся? :)", reply_markup=action)
        tb.register_next_step_handler(msg, chosen)
```

**UPDATE**

Здесь используем базу данных с юзерами

```
import telebot
from pymongo import MongoClient

tb = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

client = MongoClient()
db = client.first_db
users = db['users']

@tb.message_handler(commands=['start', 'go'])
def start_handler(message):
    msg = tb.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, отправь логин и пароль")
    tb.register_next_step_handler(msg, auth)


def auth(message):
    data = message.text.split() # создаем список ['логин', 'пароль']

    check = users.find_one({ # проверяем наличие в базе комбинации логина и пароля
        'username': str(data['username']),
        'password': str(data['password']),
    })

    if check is None: # если такой комбинации не существует, ждём команды /start Опять
        tb.send_message(message.chat.id, r'Неправильно введен логин\пароль')

    else: # а если существует, переходим к следующему шагу
        msg = tb.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что будем делать?')
        tb.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_step_func)
```

Comment: Это, к сожалению, не совсем подойдет в данном случае. мне надо как то post запрос отправить, и получить get с инфой... это весьма затруднительно когда ты джун

Comment: Максимум что можно, это отправлять боту логин+пароль, и бот будет в бд проверять наличие такой комбинации, и если она присутствует, давать на время доступ к своему функционалу

Comment: вот это идеальная комбинация которая нужна)

Comment: у меня этот блок вот так как то получается:

`@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])  
def send_text(message):  
    if message.text.lower() == 'проверить сделку':  # → авторизируйтесь (логин/пароль)    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите номер сделки')  # вывод: номер сделки, статус, рекомендации`

Comment: @Evgeniy Можно ли сделать отправку боту логина и пароля используя базу данных не MongoDB а SQLite? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще вариант авторизации на 2022 год, Aiogram 2 версии + PostgresSQL (DB GINO). Используется FSM - машинное состояние. Получаем из БД юзера если где у этого юзера указан логин и пароль для авторизации.

Код

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from filters import IsPrivate_call
from loader import dp
from states import authorization_admins
from utils.misc import rate_limit
from utils.db_api import cmd_admins as commands



# Хендлер Авторизации Админа
@rate_limit(limit=5)
# вызывается с помощью инлаин кнопки либо можете указать dp.message.handler и назначить ему команду, в моём случае через колбэк.
@dp.callback_query_handler(IsPrivate_call(), text_contains='administrator')
async def auth_admin(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer(cache_time=5)
    await call.message.answer(f'Введите Логин:')
    await authorization_admins.login.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=authorization_admins.login)
async def login(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    login = message.text
    admins = await commands.select_admin(message.from_user.id)
    if login in admins.login:
        await message.answer('Логин принят')
    else:
        await message.answer('Не правильный логин')
    await state.update_data(text=login)
    await message.answer('Введите пароль: ')
    await authorization_admins.password.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=authorization_admins.password)
async def password(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    password = message.text
    admins = await commands.select_admin(message.from_user.id)
    if password in admins.password:
        await message.answer('Пароль принят')
    else:
        await message.answer('Не правильный пароль')
    await message.answer('Вы авторизированы как Админ')
    await state.update_data(text=password)
    await state.finish()
```

Скриншот БД

[image: ПРИМЕР БД]